# 'SafeString' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Tags: python, django

I am writing a custom template tags in django. Now, I explain you briefly. My final goal is to have in my template a duration field as hours and minutes. At the moment, I have a duration field that provides also the seconds, which I am not interested to be shown. So the goal is 1 hour = 01:00 but at the moment I have 01:00:00. I wrote this function which is working when I use it in my views but, I need also to use it inside django template.

custom_tags.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag

    def duration(td):
        total_seconds = int(td.total_seconds())
        hours = total_seconds // 3600
        minutes = (total_seconds % 3600) // 60
        if minutes < 1:
            minutes = '00'
        elif minutes < 2:
            minutes = '01'
        elif minutes < 3:
            minutes = '02'
        elif minutes < 4:
            minutes = '03'
        elif minutes < 5:
            minutes = '04'
        elif minutes < 6:
            minutes = '05'
        elif minutes < 7:
            minutes = '06'
        elif minutes < 8:
            minutes = '07'
        elif minutes < 9:
            minutes = '08'
        elif minutes < 10:
            minutes = '09'
        return '{}:{}'.format(hours, minutes)
```

template

```
<td>
 {% if mix.mission.duration_dual is not None %} <strong>{% duration 'mix.mission.duration_dual' %}</strong>{% endif %}
  <div>{% if mix.log_entry.eet is not None and mix.log_entry.solo_flight == False %} {{mix.log_entry.eet|time:'G:i'}}  {% endif %}</div>
</td>
```

The views and models are quite unuseful in this case, because everything is working fine, I need just to understand if there's a way to make the time field appearing right also in this case.
The error I am having is:

```
'SafeString' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/astergest/mission/views.py", line 71, in student_mission_ppl
    return render(request, 'mission/student_mission_ppl.html', context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 176, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 168, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 153, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 168, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 214, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 295, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 977, in render
    return SafeString(''.join([
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 978, in <listcomp>
    node.render_annotated(context) for node in self
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 193, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Programmazione/Astergest/astergest/mission/templatetags/custom_tags.py", line 7, in duration
    total_seconds = int(td.total_seconds())
AttributeError: 'SafeString' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because td is a string not a timedelta. You can fix by removing the quotes from tag as follows

```
 <td>
 {% if mix.mission.duration_dual is not None %}   
 <strong>{% duration mix.mission.duration_dual 
 %}</strong>{% endif %}
 <div>{% if mix.log_entry.eet is not None and 
 mix.log_entry.solo_flight == False %} 
 {{mix.log_entry.eet|time:'G:i'}}  {% endif %}. 
 </div>
 </td>
```

Comment: Ok, how can I do that? I didn't understand what you meant entirely, sorry man

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You have been very kind in your explanation.